# C# - Regular Expression to exclude some files not working

Tags: c#, regex, file

I want to get all the .xlsx files containing in a folder except the files starting with the character ~.

I used the following regular expression, still it doesn't work.

Can someone help with this ?

```
  var fileNames =  GetFileNames(folder).Where(file => !Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file), "^[~]+.xlsx"));
```

Comment: Why not use regular `StartsWith` and `EndsWith`? `file => file.StartsWith("~") && file.EndsWith(".xlsx")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your RegEx to the following:

```
^[~]+.*\.xlsx
```

You have not specified that fileName can contain any other symbol after "~".
Also you have error writing `.xlsx` it must be `\.xlsx`. Because in the first case it will match `axlsx` too.

Comment: says "unrecognised escape sequence"

Comment: add @ before string so it will be `@"^[~]+.*\.xlsx"`

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but try this:

```
 var fileNames =  GetFileNames(folder).Where(file => !Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file), "^[~][.]{1,}.xlsx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex expression should be at least `^[~]\w+.xlsx` (add necessary if you need some more than \w+

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

`^[^~].+\.xlsx$`

This regex ignores the `~` at the beginning, and matches otherwise.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7nnCUl/2)

Comment: says "unrecognised escape sequence "

Comment: Use verbatim at the front `"@"`

Answer (score 0):

You first `^` character means the start of the string instead of negating the presence of `~`. Also, you have to escape special characters like `.` with a backslash (`\`).

The correct code would be:

```
var fileNames =  GetFileNames(folder).Where(file => !Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(file), "^[^~]+\.xlsx"));
```

It's useful to test your regex with an online tool before using it in code. I use [regex101](https://regex101.com/).